# I keep getting [u'error']

Tags: python

Why am I getting this error when trying to print keys from dictionary?

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker'))
a = json.loads(ret.read())
print a.keys()

ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24Volume'))
b = json.loads(ret.read())
print b.keys()
```

Comment: Problem is on remote server; this is not a question suitable for SE and should be deleted.

Comment: Although the problem occurs on the remote server (I just checked and it seems to be working again), your code should not crash/break if the resource is removed/offline in the future (i.e. returns a 404, 50x) or if the resource does not respond in time (timeout). Read about catching errors in urllib2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256576/catching-http-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is originating from the site. The dict is loaded, and expresses the error as it's only key.

Try this:

```
ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24hVolume'))
b = json.loads(ret.read())
print b.keys()
```

Notice the 'h' in `return24hVolume`.

Comment: I am so sorry that I bothered you with this. I indeed have the required API keys and I stripped the code to show the error only. Ive spent over an hour to figure this out and embarrassingly it was that 'h' in return24hVolume as you have pointed out. Thanks a lot. Lesson learn

Comment: @Karlos happens to us all.

Answer (score 3):

The error is produced by the website - your code as such is ok, it produces a json-object which has apparently the structure '{ "error" : ""}'. Try printing it out & figure out what's wrong, you probably need some authentication tokens or similar stuff.

There seems to be a API wrapper available, you should consider using or at least understanding it:  http://pastebin.com/8fBVpjaj

It's directly featured on polniex website, and it clearly shows the need of API secret and key.

Answer (score 0):

The second URL returns:

```
{"error":"Invalid command."}
```

So as [Reut Sharabani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/948550/reut-sharabani) points out, you have to use 'h' in the URL:

> https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24hVolume