# How to ignore HTTP Errors while scraping URLs with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, http, error-handling, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm crawling several URLs to find specific keywords in their source code. However, while crawling half of the websites, my spider suddenly stops due to HTTP errors like 404 or 503.

My crawler:

```
import urllib2

keyword = ['viewport']

with open('listofURLs.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        if strdomain:
            req = urllib2.Request(strdomain.strip())
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            html_content = response.read()

            for searchstring in keyword:
                if searchstring.lower() in str(html_content).lower():
                    print (strdomain, keyword, 'found')

f.close()
```

What code should I add to ignore bad URLs with HTTP errors and letting the crawler continue craping?

Comment: You can call getCode() on the response object and use a conditional to check for a 200 status.

Comment: @tobassist can you tell me what line of code i specifically need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a try-except block as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256576/catching-http-errors). This allows you to apply your logic to the valid urls and apply different logic to the urls that give HTTP errors.

Applying the solution in the link to your code gives.

```
import urllib2

keyword = ['viewport']

with open('listofURLs.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        if strdomain:
            req = urllib2.Request(strdomain.strip())
            try:
                response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                html_content = response.read()

                for searchstring in keyword:
                    if searchstring.lower() in str(html_content).lower():
                        print (strdomain, keyword, 'found')

            except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
                # Do something here maybe print err.code
f.close()
```

This is the right solution for the code you've provided. However, eLRuLL makes a great point that you really should look at using scrapy for your web crawling needs.

Comment: Thank you! Why is scrapy so much better than my code?

Comment: @jakeT888 `scrapy` contains all the tools and mechanisms to deal with most of the web crawling problems. On your case, it already handles bad response statuses without breaking your web crawler.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Scrapy framework](https://scrapy.org) for crawling purposes